# Google closure compiler javascript parse error

Tags: javascript, compiler-construction, closures, minify

I am trying to use google closure compiler on my javascript files. It works fine except for the following piece of code:

```
function goto(form) { var index=form.select.selectedIndex
if (form.select.options[index].value != "0") {
location=form.select.options[index].value;}}
```

The compiler returns:

> JSC_PARSE_ERROR: Parse error. missing ( before function parameters. at line 1 character 9
>   function goto(form) { var index=form.select.selectedIndex

There is a caret (^) pointing to the g in "goto" when it is output on the screen.

I am using just the basic UI version here to test:

http://closure-compiler.appspot.com/home

Any idea what is wrong with the javacript? It seems to work just fine but I am not a javascript person so I have no clue how to fix it. Thanks,

Bill

Comment: well it is missing a semicolon after `selectedIndex`, doubt that is the issue.

Answer (score 4):

I am not sure why @Sirko deleted his answer. So I will add it.

You need to change the name of the function `goto` to something else. Something like gotoUrl, gotoPage, etc.

It was a reserved word in ECMAScript 3, but removed in ECMAScript 5. I am guessing the closure compiler uses that older list still.

Comment: that fixed it, thanks! I was having flashbacks to BASIC programming when I saw that goto in the first place

Comment: Javascript has a weird and wonderful list of reserved words, most of which don't appear in the language itself, consequently they are unguessable.